# R: Sum together items in multiple lists of different length?

Tags: r

I have the following lists:

```
l1 <- list(a = 3, b = 4, c = 8, d = 1)

l2 <- list(a = 3, b = 2, c = 5, d = 1, f = 4, g = 13)
```

How can merge both lists by summing the items in both lists based on their names, as:

```
l1 + l2 = list(a=6, b=6, c=13, d=2, f=4, g=13)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could approach it with `dplyr` as follows:

```
l1 <- list(a = 3, b = 4, c = 8, d = 1)
l2 <- list(a = 3, b = 2, c = 5, d = 1, f = 4, g = 13)

library(dplyr)

bind_rows(lapply(list(l1, l2), as.data.frame)) %>%
colSums(na.rm=TRUE) %>%
as.list()
```

Comment: And for the old-fashioned, there's `rbind.fill` in plyr instead of `bind_rows`, or `rbindlist(list(l1,l2),fill=TRUE)` from data.table.

Comment: In the current version of *dplyr*, dplyr_0.4.3,  you can feed lists directly to `bind_rows` without converting them to data frames - i.e.,  `bind_rows(l1, l2)`.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to `melt` both the `list`s to data.frame, `merge` them, do the `rowSums` on the numeric columns and convert back to `list`.

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- merge(melt(l1), melt(l2), by='L1', all=TRUE)
setNames(as.list(rowSums(d1[-1], na.rm=TRUE)), d1$L1)
#$a
#[1] 6

#$b
#[1] 6

#$c
#[1] 13

#$d
#[1] 2

#$f
#[1] 4

#$g
#[1] 13
```

Or we create the unique `names` of both 'l1' and 'l2' ('nm1').  Loop over 'nm1', `replace` the NULL elements with 0 and do the `+`.

```
 nm1 <- union(names(l1), names(l2))
 lapply(nm1, function(x) {v1 <- l1[[x]]
                          v2 <- l2[[x]]
                         replace(v1, is.null(v1), 0) +
                         replace(v2, is.null(v2), 0)    

     })
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach,

```
l1 <- list(a = 3, b = 4, c = 8, d = 1)
l2 <- list(a = 3, b = 2, c = 5, d = 1, f = 4, g = 13)
a <- l1[intersect(names(l1), names(l2))] 
b <- l2[intersect(names(l1), names(l2))]
ab <- as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)

c <- as.numeric(l1[!(l1 %in% a)])
d <- as.numeric(l2[!(l2 %in% b)])

c(ab, c, d)
# [1]  6  6 13  2  4 13
```